# Can I run an MDX query in pentaho?

Tags: mdx, pentaho

I have an MDX query I built by hand.  I want to run it and see my results.  Is there anyway I can run it on Pentaho?  There are plenty of drag and drop to build my MDX query.  But I want to paste one in (Or upload, or whatever)  Is there a way to do that?  Or a plugin I could use?

Comment: I don't work in Pentaho, but did a quick search on this. Probably this might help: http://helicaltech.com/using-mdx-query-pentaho-cde/

Comment: Do you have a Mondrian schema written? You need that to convert your MDX to SQL